# How to save to database the value on a multiline textbox or how to save to database a non-delimited text on a textfile

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex, textbox

I Have a textfile that has a value of multiple row text that don't have delimiter.

Here is the sample text on my textfile.

000100000080020201000000005309970000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003F
00010001008002020100010000530997000014820000148200010000012C00001482000014820000148200010000012C000014820000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000003F

then i must devide each every line in this format.

"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXX-XX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX".Split('-');

the out put is like this.

00010000-0080-02020100000000-53-0997-00000000-00000000-0000-00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000-0000-00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000-0000-00000000-00000000-00000001-00000000-0000-00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000-0000-00000000-00000000-000000-00-00000000-00000000-0000-00000000-0000003F
00010001-0080-02020100010000-53-0997-00001482-00001482-0001-0000012C-00001482-00001482-00001482-0001-0000012C-00001482-00000000-00000000-0000-00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000-0000-00000000-00000000-00000000-00000000-0000-00000000-00000000-010100-00-00000000-00000000-0000-00000000-0000003F

i imported it into a multiline textbox.

here is my code

private void btn_input_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string content;
            content = File.ReadAllText(txt_path.Text);

```
        string[] patern = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXX-XX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX".Split('-');

        string mystring = content;

        string regex = string.Empty;
        string match = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < patern.Length; i++)
        {
            regex += @"(\w{" + patern[i].Length + "})";
            match += "$" + (i + 1).ToString() + "-";
        }
        match = match.Substring(0, match.Length - 1);

        txt_textfile.Text = Regex.Replace(mystring, regex, match);

    }
```

then i want to save to my database the text that i split in ('-'). but i dont know how to do it. I want to ask is there is something i can do for me to able to save it. Even in while importing it. or after importing it. anyway. Please Help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not that much clear.
all you have done there is format your input string.

I'm not sure about the way that you want to insert the values to database.
just guessing that you want to split the formatted text by '-' and insert that split values 
one by one

in that case what you have to do is split the text in txt_textfile text box and get string array.
loop the array and insert values the database.

if this is not the answer that you looked for please comment here the exact thing that you want to do
Thanks :)